# Elixir - passing function parameter through

Tags: elixir, function-parameter

Say I have a function, that's slightly verbose and is called with the same arguments each time, this function is also required a lot to do some setup before any other functions from that module can be called within its callback.

```
SomeMod.called_a_lot(‘xx’, fn(y) ->
  SomeMod.needs_called_a_lot_to_be_called_first(‘do_stuff’)
end)
```

I imagine that I can wrap it like so:

```
defp easier_to_call(func) do
  SomeMod.called_a_lot(‘xx’, fn(y) -> func(y) end
end
```

then use it like so:

```
easier_to_call(fn(y) ->
  SomeMod.needs_called_a_lot_to_be_called_first(‘do_stuff’)
end)
```

How does one *actually* do this in Elixir?

Comment: Your code looks fine; just change `func(y)` to `func.(y)` since it's an anonymous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is just a bit off for calling anonymous functions.  You will need to use

```
func.(y)
```

instead of

```
func(y)
```

since it is an anonymous function.

See the [Elixir Crash Course](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#anonymous-functions) for a brief example.

Answer (score 1):

Dogbert's comment is correct. But since you don't modify the arguments, you could just pass the function on without wrapping it in an anonymous function:

```
defp easier_to_call(func) do
  SomeMod.called_a_lot(‘xx’, func)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what exactly you're asking, but I feel like the [capture operator (`&`)](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.4.2/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1) is what you're looking for.

An example use would be:

```
easier_func = &SomeMod.called_a_lot(‘xx’, &1)

easier_func.(fn(_y) ->
  SomeMod.needs_called_a_lot_to_be_called_first(‘do_stuff’)
end)
```

With `&1` being the first parameter in the anonymous function.

If you need a multiple arity anonymous function then you can do:

```
easy_reduce = &Enum.reduce(&1, 0, &2)

easy_reduce.([1,2,3,4], fn(x, acc) -> acc + x end) # => 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to show another approach: it might be achieved with macro, that calls the function to be called first and then calls the block:

```
defmodule Test do
  defmacro with_prepended(arg, do: block) do
    quote do
      IO.inspect(unquote(arg), label: "In function")
      prepended(unquote(arg))
      unquote(block)
    end
  end
end

defmodule Tester do
  require Test

  defp prepended(arg), do: IO.inspect(arg, label: "In prepended")

  def fun(arg) do
    Test.with_prepended(arg) do
      IO.puts "Actual code"
    end
  end
end

Tester.fun(42)

#⇒ In function: 42
#⇒ In prepended: 42
#⇒ Actual code
```